# Windows Phone: refresh a binded listbox "manually"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, binding

the question seems to be easy, but I didn't find responses to this question.

I have my list of items working perfectly, binded to my MVVM. When I update an element, all is coordinated well, changes are reflected, etc.

One of my fields is calculated depending on the current day. So, if the user press HOME and exits the App, and tomorrow he comes back, the list is not refreshed, it is showing the previous day data.

To resolve this, I thought in use the `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom` events, saving the "entrance" day at start and compare it with the current day in the `OnNavigatedTo` event (which is fired when resuming the App). Detecting this day change, I could refresh the list explicity.

The question is, how I refresh the list? Or maybe I'm complicating the things a bit and there is a better way to do this.

EDIT: Final solution.

For those who need the same functionality, here is the solution I found:

```
    // Declare this var in the MainPage class
    // Holds the starting app day. If when going back to this page it has changed, refresh the list
    private DateTime loadDate;

    // Save the current day. If when going back to here it has changed, refresh the list
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        loadDate = DateTime.Today;
    }

    // Read the current day and compare with saved. If when going back to here it has changed, refresh the list
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Read the current day and compare
        if (loadDate != DateTime.Today)
        {
            // The day has changed. Loop the list to refresh every item
            foreach (Item item in listBoxControl.Items)
            {
                item.CalculateMyOwnFieldNotBindedToDB();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaberate on why the above isnt working? Can you provide some code perhaps? That is the standard when posting on Stack Overflow

Comment: Does your VM implement INotifyPropertyChanged?
Raising PropertyChanged event defined by this interface is usually used to 'refresh' bindings in MVVM.

Comment: Just make sure you're raising it on the UI thread.

Comment: @AMR, maybe you didn't understand my question. I was looking for a concept, not for explicit code. And the above is working, but I also need a method to refresh when no data has changed in the model.

Comment: @Dmitry, yes, I have INotifyPropertyChanged and when the data in the model changes, all is refreshed accordingly, the problem is that no data is changed, what changes is the internal date of the system, which is used to show a calculated value in the list (not binded to anything, just calculated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is if you raise property change on a List without actually changing the List, it will be actually ignored because the view will detect that the List object has actually not changed. One workaround for that could be to just set the List to null and then set it back to the original List.
Another solution would be to just loop through the items in the List and Raise a property change just on your date field like this it will not require the whole list to be refreshed just the actual property.

Comment: Umm, so the question is not so trivial as I expected. You are right, raising a false property change will do nothing, because nothing changes. I will try tomorrow the workaround you said, about setting to null and re-setting to the original. I'm still surprised that no one thought about this when designing the whole framework. Something so simple as refresh "when you want".

Comment: finally I resolved it with your 3th option: looping through the list and recalculating the field again, which raises a notify and refreshes the UI. The 1st (raise the notify without any change) and 2nd (set ListBox.ItemSource to null and set it again) solutions didn't work. Also I tried to completely reload, in the VM, the ObservableCollection<Item> _allItems, querying the DB again, but again this didn't work. Thanks for given me the point.